# How to initialize a NSFetchedResultsController in iOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I can't get my `NSFetchedResultsController` initialized in iOS 10 using Swift 3 within CoreDataTableViewController from [AECoreDataUI](https://github.com/tadija/AECoreDataUI).

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NasaPicture>(entityName:"NasaPicture")  
request.predicate = Predicate(format: "isPagedResult == YES")  
request.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]  
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

Compiler is complaining that

```
"Cannot convert value of type NSFetchedResultsController<NasaPicture> to expected type NSFetchedResultsController<_>"
```

The controller is now using generic type for swift, but it is not inferring the entity type correctly. I've tried explicitly:

```
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NasaPicture>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

No luck either.

Thanks!

Comment: it's your variable declaration. You cannot use `var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?` any more, you have to use `var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NasaPicture>?`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`NSFetchRequest` is now a generic. `NSFetchedResultsController` is a generic too. Therefore, when declaring variables, you have to use a generic declaration, e.g.:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NasaPicture>?
```

Comment: My view controller has a superclass CoreDataCollectionViewController that declares the frc. Because it can be reused, I can't bind the frc to a specific type when it's declared in the superclass. Unless I add a generic type parameter at the base class?

Comment: Ok so the problem was in my base class - I had to add a type parameter of T:NSFetchRequestResult, use T wherever I was using NSFetchRequestResult, and have subclasses provide the Entity they want to use with it.

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin Can you show specifically what you did? I'm having a bear of a time declaring a frc lazily, specifying a predicate, sort descriptors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

when we need to declare variable, then we have to use a generic declaration
please check below code for NSFetchedResultsController in swift 3..

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

}
 // MARK: - NSFetchedResultsController

```
fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExistenceOnXMPPCD> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserExistenceOnXMPPCD>(entityName: "UserExistenceOnXMPPCD")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:CoreDataController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    if let quotes = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
        if quotes.count > 0 {
            print(quotes.count)
        }
    }
    return fetchedResultsController
}()


// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)  {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)  {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply call the function:

```
private func setupFetchedResultsController() {

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Month>(entityName: "Month")
    let dateDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateDescriptor]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "year", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```