# Difficulty configuring NSFetchedResultsController in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3

I'm refactoring an existing project from Swift 2 to Swift 3. Everything has been straightforward until I got to refactoring Core Data. I'm able to create managed objects and persist them in the `managedObjectContext`, but I'm having difficulty getting `NSFetchedResultsController` to work. I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036925/how-to-initialize-a-nsfetchedresultscontroller-in-ios-10-swift-3), but it's not getting me across the finish line.

After importing records from a JSON, I verify there are objects in my `managedObjectContext` with the following code:

```
func recordCount() -> Int {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
    let count = try! context.count(for: fetchRequest)
    return count
}
```

When I create a `fetchedResultsController`, I'm running into trouble. My code doesn't crash, but it doesn't return `NSManagedObjects` despite there being objects that match my search.

Here's how I'm creating my `NSFetchedResultsController` in a `UIViewController`.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    // This is set on a prior viewController before segue.
    // I've verified it's not nil
    var selectedEquipmentString: String?

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<MyEntity> = {
        // I've tried altering the syntax of the fetchRequest
        // let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyEntity> = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "generalArea", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "equipmentDescription == %@", self.selectedEquipmentString!)
        let frc: NSFetchedResultsController<MyEntity> = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "generalArea", cacheName: nil)
        frc.delegate = self
        return frc
    }()

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle Methods (abbreviated)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // I've tried moving this call to viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear without success
        fetchObjectsFromManagedObjectContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data Methods (abbreviated)
    func fetchObjectsFromManagedObjectContext() {
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        print ("There are \(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count) returned from fetchObjectsFromManagedObjectContext")
    }
}
```

This code doesn't crash, but it doesn't return any records from a fetchRequest. I was able to force a crash with a typo in the predicate, but without a typo there are no objects returned despite objects that match the predicate.

I welcome any suggestions re: where my mistake is. I rest assured knowing it will be a startlingly silly oversight on my part. Thank you for reading.

Comment: The obvious question seems to be, are you certain that your predicate matches any of the objects you've saved? Your `recordCount` method doesn't use the predicate but your fetched results controller does, so if nothing matches the predicate, nothing would be found.

Comment: @TomHarrington Thank you for reading. My first thought was a problem w/ the predicate, too. I've copied working code from the Swift 2 project to this project (updating syntax to Swift 3) and I've kept attribute names the same on the Swift 3 project's managed objects, which made me think I've got a problem with configuration the FRC.

Comment: Yes but do you know something about the data that makes you certain that some of the objects match the predicate? Equivalent code is irrelevant if nothing matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NSFetchRequest should have a type `NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>`, but you specify `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>`. Try changing this and let me know if it helps or not

Answer (score 0):

please check below code for NSFetchedResultsController swift 3..

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

}
 // MARK: - NSFetchedResultsController

```
fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExistenceOnXMPPCD> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserExistenceOnXMPPCD>(entityName: "UserExistenceOnXMPPCD")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:CoreDataController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    if let quotes = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
        if quotes.count > 0 {
            print(quotes.count)
        }
    }
    return fetchedResultsController
}()


// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)  {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)  {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```