# Using fetchedResultsController with swift3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I wanna use `fetchedResultsController` in my code with Swift3. I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036925/how-to-initialize-a-nsfetchedresultscontroller-in-ios-10-swift-3) and other ways, but I can't make it. Here is my code(it doesn't work):

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Entity> {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Entity>
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        fetchRequest = Entity.fetchRequest()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
    }

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let orderDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "archiveOrder", ascending: true)
    let nameDesctiptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "entityName", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [orderDescriptor, nameDesctiptor]

    let aFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Entity> = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _FetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }

    return _FetchedResultsController!
}
```

Could you please give me any advice or suggestions?

Comment: I found the solution. I added @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entity> {
        return NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
    } in my Entity class and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Apple recommends to declare `NSFetchedResultsController` as non-optional lazy initialized property using a closure which runs the code in the closure only once.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = { ... }()
```

Your code doesn't compile because Swift code is case sensitive that means `_fetchedResultsController` and `_FetchedResultsController` are two different things.

The rest of the code seems to be correct.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Entity> = {

  let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Entity>
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    fetchRequest = Entity.fetchRequest()
  } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
  }
  fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

  let orderDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "archiveOrder", ascending: true)
  let nameDesctiptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "entityName", ascending: false)

  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [orderDescriptor, nameDesctiptor]

  let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, 
                                                     managedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext, 
                                                       sectionNameKeyPath: nil, 
                                                                cacheName: "Master")
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

  do {
    try aFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
  } catch {
    let nserror = error as NSError
    print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
  }

  return aFetchedResultsController
}()
```

Comment: When I put 'lazy', I got the error message saying, "'lazy' may not be used on a computed property", so I deleted it.

Comment: Also, following Xcode's suggestion, I put     fetchRequest = Entity.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Entity>

Comment: It's **not** a computed property. Consider the pair of parentheses at the end of the method.

Comment: Now there is no error on my Xcode, but when I run, I had an error saying *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext'

Comment: Follow the code in the Core Data template which provides a non-nil `NSManagedObjectContext`

Comment: I think I have a correct NSManagedObjectContext in my AppDelegate.swift

Comment: lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

Comment: Is the way to get appDelegate incorrect?   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

Comment: `appDelegate` is correct but something must be optional. Set breakpoints and find out

Comment: I found out that fetchRequest is nil, but I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Entity>
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            fetchRequest = Entity.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Entity>
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
        }

Comment: @vadian It's a computed property the way it's written and won't compile. You need to add an equal sign before the first bracket to make it an initialized property.