# How to get live value from CoreData Or know if value is change from last fetch value in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am fetching value from `Coredata` and showing it in a `UItableView` but after showing values in `UITableView` there are few values are updated by another thread. Now want know a way to reflect those changes in my `UITableView`, Please let know if there is any way to achieve this.

**Solution:**

Thanks [Giuseppe Lanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1754559/giuseppe-lanza) and [bobnoble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724514/bobnoble) for the right direction i used this [video link - Swift: FB Messenger - How to Auto Update using NSFetchedResultsController](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JJJ2WGpw_I) to understand `NSFetchedResultsController` but it's code also outdated so I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41676934/3851580) post to update code. And the final code is

Declare NSFetchedResultsController in class

```
 var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>?
```

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.setupFetchedResultsController()
```

and write new method setupFetchedResultsController as

```
private func setupFetchedResultsController() {

        let context = CoreDataStack.getContext()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Sites")
        let nameDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "siteName", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [nameDescriptor]

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest , managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }
    }
```

And use delegate as

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        if(type == .update)
        {
            tblView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are a couple of options - use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, or listen for a managed object change notification such as `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

Comment: Do you have any example for the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that NSFetchedResultsController is what you need.
From apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller):

> While table views can be used in several ways, fetched results
> controllers are primarily intended to assist you with a master list
> view. UITableView expects its data source to provide cells as an array
> of sections made up of rows. You configure a fetch results controller
> using a fetch request that specifies the entity, an array containing
> at least one sort ordering, and optionally a filter predicate.

[...]

> In addition, fetched results controllers provide
> the following features:
>
> Optionally monitor changes to objects in the associated managed object context, and report changes in the results set to its delegate (see The Controller’s Delegate).
>
> Optionally cache the results of its computation so that if the same data is subsequently re-displayed, the work does not have to be repeated (see The Cache).

Here is a tutorial that explains how to use it:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is a swift tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-25072

Comment: Both example are for `Objective-C' do you have any swift example ?

Comment: Updated my answer with a swift tutorial